# Unable to scroll embedded pdf on safari (IPAD)

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, pdf

I show pdf in IPAD with below code,

```
    <embed src="pdfPath" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" />
```

With this approach, I see just the 1st page of pdf. I'm not able to scroll and see the rest of pdf.

The same code works on desktop chrome.

I tried changing different heights, also tried adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` as suggested in other answers, but nothing seems to help.

IOS version: 10.0.2

Comment: Can you scroll on the same website on a Computer? Also, try adding any info that might be relevant. Like browsers, Live link, some more code. See also: [mcve].

Comment: I tried on desktop chrome, and it works

Comment: Aha, thanks. Please add the above to your post.